# iOS app not appearing in google search

Tags: ios, search, app-store, itunes

I have my application live on both ios app store and google play store, but when I search for my app with same name or whatever keyword, Google Play app appears in search results but ios app never appear in search results. Any reason ?

Comment: i've been waiting for more than 2 weeks and still not showing ,, have you configure it out ??

Comment: No, no solution was found, apparently something went wrong with Google's indexing, After some months it started appearing in search results, but still if I don't write "itunes" with my app name, it doesn't appear in search results.